# Rounded corners without disabling hardwareacceleration

Tags: java, android, rounded-corners

I'm trying to add rounded corners to a custom drawed view. I recently found out the solution, but there has to be a better way i guess?

To add the corners, i'm using a path:

```
Path mPath = new Path();
        mPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, 100,100),20,20, Path.Direction.CCW);
        canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
```

But this only works, if I add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to my manifest and I really don't want to add this line, as it slows down the app a lot!

Can i get this to run without disabling the hardwareacceleration?

Comment: Isn't it possible to draw the round rect 'normally' ?
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint)

Comment: Yes that's right, the problem is that i'm drawing some sort of statistic and there are many different objects, lines, ... so it would be too difficult to round up all of them, so i thought it would be more easy to give the whole view rounded edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to partially disable hardwareacceleration. I just disabled the hardwareacceleration for the view, where i needed the rounded corners, so the performance of the app doesn't got affected too much.

Hope this helps others, who are forced with the same problem.